# Downloading via SDK manager works but adding dependencies through gradle fails in android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, windows-10, build.gradle

I am currently facing some problems with android studio. It works fine when I download things via SDK manager or update android studio components but gradle dependencies download shows timeout after trying for some time. I have a decent internet connection. Cannot figure out where is the problem. Tried every configuration I know from windows firewall but nothing seems to work. I am not using any proxy.

Comment: Are you behind any proxy?

Comment: No. It wasn't working with proxy aslo, but now I am not using any.